# How to override different types of generic type

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I save my operation types in a queue with the template below. For example one operation type is `connectToBluetooth`, another operation type is `sendMessageToBluetooth`. Because of this Each operation should be able to return a different type of result.

```
sealed class Resource<out T:Any>{
    abstract val data:T?
    data class Success<out T:Any> (override val data:T? = null):Resource<T>()
    data class Error<out T:Any>(override val data:T? = null, val errorMessage:String? = null):Resource<T>()
    data class Loading<out T:Any>(override val data:T? = null, val message:String? = null):Resource<T>()
}

abstract class OperationType {
    abstract val result: ((Resource<String>) -> Unit)
}

data class Operation1(override val result: ((Resource<String>) -> Unit)): OperationType()

var nextPendingOperation: OperationType? = null
fun performOperation1(result: ((Resource<String>) -> Unit)) {
    nextPendingOperation = Operation1(result) 
}

fun main() {
    performOperation1() {
        
    }
    
    var nextPendingOperation2 = nextPendingOperation
    if ( nextPendingOperation2 is Operation1 ) {
        nextPendingOperation2.result(Resource.Loading("message"))
    }
}
```

But in the above structure, `result` `data` type is always `string`. The code below does not working. How can i made this code to work for this purpose?

```
abstract class OperationType {
    abstract val result: ((Resource<Any>) -> Unit)
}

data class Operation1(override val result: ((Resource<String>) -> Unit)): OperationType()
data class Operation2(override val result: ((Resource<Int>) -> Unit)): OperationType()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `OperationType` accept a generic parameter, so that you can have different operations work on different resource types.

```
abstract class OperationType<T: Any> {
    abstract val result: ((Resource<T>) -> Unit)
}

data class Operation1(override val result: ((Resource<String>) -> Unit)): OperationType<String>()
data class Operation2(override val result: ((Resource<Int>) -> Unit)): OperationType<Int>()

var nextPendingOperation: OperationType<*>? = null
fun performOperation1(result: ((Resource<String>) -> Unit)) {
    nextPendingOperation = Operation1(result)
}

fun main() {
    val nextPendingOperation2 = nextPendingOperation
    when (nextPendingOperation2) {
        is Operation1 -> nextPendingOperation2.result(Resource.Loading("message"))
        is Operation2 -> nextPendingOperation2.result(Resource.Loading(1))
    }
}
```

Comment: also can you edit this code to show how to define nextPendingOperation?